# Can't configure antMatchers after anyRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I saw several people saying that this problem is because of .anyRequest (). Authenticated () to be used only once, but I am using it no time.

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.factory.PasswordEncoderFactories;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties;

import com.atlantico.service.UserDetailsService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order(SecurityProperties.IGNORED_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/csrf",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/*.html",
                        "/*.js",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/webjars/**",
                        "/configuration/**",
                        "/h2/**",
                        "/swagger-resources/**",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
        http.headers().cacheControl();
    }
   
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
    }


}
```

I don't know what it can be anymore.
Even removing the entire class gives the same error.
I am suspicious that it may be a matter of setting an order, but I have already tried and the error continued. Possible that my @Order statement is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Solution I found:
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)